# React, Vue, Angular, etc., how to handle errors application wide?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, vue.js

Let's say I have application (no matter, what is on frontend).

Backend is just API.

There are many pages/forms. Every page/form requires some interaction with API.

Many errors can arise:

```
 1. User is disconnected from network
 2. User is not authenticated 
 3. API for some reason returns unexpected 500 code
```

It is bad to code handling of these errors in every form and every page (because we want to notify user that something went wrong) so it must be done in one place.

In Vue, for example, I can setup http interceptor, which swallows disconnected network error and 500 errors and shows info to user.

But some things can be bad, like web app checks some API every N seconds, so every N seconds it will show error (if network is disconnected).

Where can I read about web app architecture to remove code duplication like this?

Another thing, showing user that app is processing it's request

In React as I know I can make Redux store with something like

```
{
    "loading": false
}
```

Then every page/form dispatches action, which makes loading = true, upon finishing request sets loading=false so in some top level component I can show loading spinner.

Where to read about such cases?

P.S. Question, as I think, is mostly about central state object (like in Redux).
So what are best solutions to handle errors on frontend in one place?
May be there are some good articles about designing application state?

Comment: Why would you want to handle the errors on every page? What good is it to show a user an error 500 code when something is going wrong? It is fine if you might be creating something for other programmers but they can deal with this by using their network tab. If you want to know if something went wrong you can use a Javascript logger like sentry.

Comment: It's not for developers, it's for end users because they must see that something went wrong so they know that data is not saved

Comment: Handle your network error handling in your network handling class. If you don't have a network handling class and you're reproducing code over and over you're not designing the application correctly. It sounds like you need to learn object oriented development first.

Answer (score 0):

You question is quite broad and it really depends on your app and framework, but i'll try to pinpoint some common use cases:

1. Every framework has the interceptors concept (Vue,Angular,React), and it's good to use them as you suggested
2. Regarding the case you mentioned, that the app pings an API and notifies the user many time - you can easily get over it by using a boolean like `showedMessage`, if it's false you turn it to true and show the message to the user, next time the network is back, you turn it back to false. that way you only show the network down message, once.
3. Redux is not unique to React and there are implementations for angular ([ngrx](https://github.com/ngrx)) and Vue ([vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/)), they all work on the same concept of handling one major state object that all the components share. This is the recommended method as of now. Another option is [mobx](https://mobx.js.org/), but it's less common and I think only react has an implementation for it.
4. Another way is to use custom events but i would only recommend it for small apps that have no more than 5 event types, otherwise you'll loose track of what's happening real soon.